# Unable to open X11 Windows from VSCode terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, x11, xorg

I am trying to run a very simple script from within VSCode.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("test.png")

im.show()
```

Whenever I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
No Protocol Specified.

display: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/411
```

This works in my normal terminal, alacritty. I am running an Arch Linux X11 system with BSPWM as my window manager. Please help!

Comment: -Have you run this code in a Python interactive window outside of VSCode?

Comment: Can you open a VSCode terminal and post the output of `echo $DISPLAY`?

Comment: @JillCheng Yes, and it runs as expected.

Comment: @Albo Returns nothing. I have also noticed that the VSCode terminal has trouble interacting with BSPWM's  `bspc` client.

Comment: @alexacallmebaka -Which VSCode extensions did you use?

Comment: @JillCheng Python and Discord Presence.

Comment: @alexacallmebaka -Does it work when you use the absolute path of the picture? Please try to disable the extension "Discord Presence".

Comment: Can you check if you manually set a display inside VSCode terminal with `export DISPLAY=:1` (or `:0`) and then run the script?

Comment: @Albo It did not work.

Comment: @JillCheng Same error.

Comment: @alexacallmebaka -Which language service are you using? (For example: _"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",_)
Could you please provide us with the content of your settings file "settings.json"?

Comment: @JillCheng I solved it! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true` in `settings.json`.